# How to generate wsp for master page what i created in designer and how it deploy into sharepoint site?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have created masterpage in designer .and anyone can help me to create wsp file for my master page. once if this masterpage(wsp) is deployed will all sub sites comes with new masterpage?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new SharePoint empty project in Visual Studio and you can deploy custom master pages using Modules. Add module in your project and include custom master pages in module to deploy to your site.

For more information visit this link:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vssharepointtoolsblog/archive/2010/04/19/how-to-deploy-a-custom-content-master-and-use-it-in-an-application-page.aspx